# Passing array of images to html div (Facebook JS SDK)

Tags: php, jquery, json

i am able to retrieve a facebook users images and console log them with the code snippet below.

```
  FB.api('/v2.2/me/photos/', function(response) { //User Photos
    var obj = response.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        // Do something with object
         console.log(obi[i].source); 
        }
    });
```

I am having an issue passing the array of images to a div, i have tried the method below but it only returns one image url.

```
$("#user_album").val(obi[i].source);
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Just a guess: for each iteration over the array you are overwriting the image with the next one. Try to create a new div for each image and insert it inside the main div

Comment: what you actually want? `$("#user_album").val(obi[i].source);` it will set the value of user_album only last image

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want it.But  following code will add the image source to your div(id=user_album)

```
FB.api('/v2.2/me/photos/', function(response) { //User Photos
var obj = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    // Do something with object
     $("#user_album").append(obi[i].source);
    }
});
```

It may help you or you may get idea.